# Replication Snapshot Agent file naming

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication

When SQL Server Snapshot Agent creates a snapshot (for transactional replication), there's a bunch of .PRE, .SCH, .BCP, and .IDX files, usually prefixed with the object name, a sequence number and part number. Like MY_TABLE_1#1.bcp for MY_TABLE.

But when table names are a little longer like MY_TABLE_IS_LONG it can name the files like MY_TABLE_IS_LO890be30c_1#1.

I want to process some of these files manually (i.e. grab a snapshot and process the BCPs myself) but that requires the full name of the table, and I haven't been able to find where that hex number is created from or stored. They don't appear to be a straight object_id, and I've checked various backing tables in the distribution and publication databases where the tables have an objid and sycobjid and it's neither of those either (after converting hex to decimal).

Does anyone know where that number comes from? It must be somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears they're just random. What happens is when the snapshot is generated a set of commands are placed into the distribution database (you can see them with EXEC sp_browsereplcmds) and these have the hardcoded table name along with the script names, and in what order to run them.

When you run the distribution agent for the first time, it gets those replicated commands, and these instruct it to run all the scripts (alternately, if you've got it set to replication support only, I suspect these commands are just ignored).

In order to process the scripts semi-automatically you'd need to grab everything from replcmds (hopefully on a quiet system) and parse the commands before running them manually.